# Converting a nested callback to a Promise

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, ecmascript-6, eslint

I would like to try and convert this function into a `Promise` based function in order to resolve all of these nested callbacks and `return` warnings from [ESLint consistent-return](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return).

Previously, I asked for some help in overcoming an ESLint error with my return statements here as they are not consistent or following the best practices of JS.

My first thought was to simply do `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})` inside the `remove` function, but that would just promisify the whole thing instead of just what's inside the function so I feel like that's not the best way to do this.

Any help appreciated!

```
function remove(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }, (findErr, existingUser) => {
    if (findErr) return res.status(500).send(errorHandler.getErrorMessage(findErr));
    if (!existingUser) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'User not found' });

    existingUser.remove((removeErr) => {
      if (removeErr) return res.status(500).send(errorHandler.getErrorMessage(removeErr));

      return res.json({ message: `${existingUser.username} successfully deleted` });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What library are you using for thsoe `findOne` and `remove` calls? Does it support promises somehow (possibly by simply omitting the callback)?

Comment: Just using plain mongoose for the database querying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way you can do it. I started by "promisifying" each `findOne` and `removeUser` as separate functions. Then, your route is almost automatically simplified.

There's still some improvements you could make here, but perhaps there's something you can learn from this.

(Thanks @Bergi for the useful recommendations)

```
const error = (type, message) => Object.assign(new Error(message), {type});
const wrapError = type => err => { throw error(type, errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err));};

const findUser = opts => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.findOne(opts, (err, user) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(user);
    });
  }).then(user => {
    if (!user) throw error('USER_NOT_FOUND', 'User not found')
    else return user;
  }, wrapError('USER_FIND_ERROR'));
};

const removeUser = user => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    user.remove(err => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve();
    });
  }).catch(wrapError('USER_REMOVE_ERROR'));
};

function remove(req, res) {
  findUser({ username: req.params.username })
    .then(removeUser)
    .then(() => res.json({message: `${req.params.username} successfully removed`}))
    .catch(error) => {
      switch (error.type) {
        case 'USER_NOT_FOUND':
          return res.status(404).send(error.message);
        // case 'USER_FIND_ERROR':
        // case 'USER_REMOVE_ERROR':
        default:
          console.error(error.type, error.message, error.stack);
          return res.status(500).send(error.message);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to do keep the promisification simple and only use `if (err) reject(err) else resolve(…);`. If you need anything else, such as those `errorHandler.getErrorMessage` calls or the emptyness test, do that in a `then` or `catch` handler.

Comment: How about `const error = (type, message) => Object.assign(new Error(message), {type});`?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the suggestions. Can you elaborate on the first comment you made a little bit more? Feel free to edit this answer if that's easier ^_^

Comment: I just did :-) Doing transformations is safer in promise callbacks than inside the plain callback of the promisification.

Comment: @Bergi very nice. Thanks for the coop ^_^

Comment: @Bergi Not sure I understand what's happening with the `Object.assign` syntax that you added. By the time it gets to `.catch(error)`, the error itself is `undefined`?

Comment: @Bergi My mistake, forgot to add `return` before `Object.assign` after I added `{ }` to the body of the function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if got your point but you may want to try the following

```
const findUser = (username) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.findOne({ username }, (error, user) => {
      if (error) {
        reject({ type: 'error', details: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(error) });
        return;
      }

      if (!user) {
        reject({ type: 'not-found', details: { message: 'User not found' } });
        return;
      }

      resolve(user);
    });
  });
};

const removeUser = (username) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    findUser(username)
      .then(user => {
        user.remove((error) => {
          if (error) {
            reject({ type: 'error', details: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(error) });
            return;
          }

          // Simply resolve on success
          resolve();
        });
      })
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
};

function remove(req, res) {
  removeUser(req.params.username)
    .then(() => res.json({ message: `${req.params.username} successfully deleted` }))
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.type === 'not-found') {
        return res.status(404).send(error.details);
      }

      return res.status(500).send(error.details);
    });
}
```

As you might have noticed above, some of the behaviours have been extracted to functions that return Promises.

Could have possibly been optimised even more but I just wanted to show you what's possible with Promises.

Does that help?

Comment: Interesting, so using the Promise logic, it would solve both my callback problem and my consistent-return problem. To point me in the right direction, what optimisations did you mean when you said that this could be further optimised? Asking as it looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) in `removeUser`!

Comment: Here's a slightly optimised version: https://gist.github.com/maciejsmolinski/c176cb27c5a2d81104acd95ce10715ca

Comment: And here's what you want to typically do with promises: https://gist.github.com/maciejsmolinski/a0007bfc2369947e1c365c61429d9742

Comment: @Bergi totally agree but please notice the nested `user.remove` API call which does not return a promise itself, would have done it differently otherwise

Comment: Interesting, so all goes well and it runs through the .then calls. Any issues and it gets sent to the .catch call at the end. I'd say it follows the typical promise syntax, but maybe with a couple extra steps due to the Mongoose functions not returning promises and instead just returning the error.

Comment: @MaciejSmoliński If you put the `new Promise` (for `user.remove` only) inside the `then` callback, it will be fine.